# How to force loop to wait until user press submit button?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback

I have simple function which checks if entered pin code is valid. But i don't know how to force for-loop to wait until i enter code again to check again it's validity.
So how it should be - i type PIN code, then **click OK button** and it checks whether it's correct (if it is, i can see my account menu; if it's not i have to type it again and i have 2 chances left). My code fails, because PIN when code is wrong program should wait until i type new code and **press OK button again**.
I tried setTimeout(), callback(), but it doesn't work. This is what i have - a function with for-loop that just runs 3 times (as it is suppose to, but not instantly) without giving a chance to correct the PIN code.

That's whole, unfinished yet, code: http://jsfiddle.net/j1yz0zuj/

Only function with for-loop, which checks validity of PIN code:

```
var submitKey = function(callback)
{
    console.log("digit status" + digitStatus);
    if (digitStatus == 0)
    {
        correctPIN = 1234;
        var onScreen = document.getElementById("screen");
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if (onScreen.innerHTML.slice(15, onScreen.innerHTML.length) == correctPIN)
            {
               setTimeout(accountMenu, 1250);
               //break;
            }
            else
            {
                onScreen.innerHTML += "<br> Błędny kod PIN! Wpisz PIN ponownie. <br> Pozostało prób: " + (2-i);
                callback();
                //cardInserted = function(function(){console.log("Ponowne wpisanie PINu");});
            }
            if (i=2) console.log("blokada");
        }
    }
    else if (digitStatus == 1)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: Set counter out of loop, and increment it when user make mistake...

Comment: E.g. something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L8adz4nd/1/ I believe you could see principle, and apply it to your code...

Comment: `if (i=2)` is not a conditional it is an assignment

Comment: @nevermind, I know what you mean and understand it, but it doesnt seem to increment when user make mistake in my code.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss, yes i know :) I just mistyped it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. You should not make the user wait!!! You need 2 more variables at the top of your programm pincount=0 and pininputallowed. Increase pincount in the submit key function by 1 and then check if pincount<3.

Here is a corrected version of your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvsx0kkx/16/

```
var pinCount=0,
pinAllowed=true;


var submitKey = function()
{
    console.log("digit status" + digitStatus);
    if (digitStatus == 0)
    {
        correctPIN = 1234;
        var onScreen = document.getElementById("screen");
        pinCount++;
        if(pinCount >= 3) {
            pinAllowed = false;
            onScreen.innerHTML = "<br>blokada";
        }
        if(pinAllowed){
            if (onScreen.innerHTML.slice(15, onScreen.innerHTML.length) == correctPIN)
            {
               setTimeout(accountMenu, 1250);
               //break;
            }
            else
            {
                onScreen.innerHTML += "<br> Błędny kod PIN! Wpisz PIN ponownie. <br> Pozostało prób: " + (3-pinCount); 
                inputLength = 0;
                document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML += "<br>Wpisz kod PIN: ";
                //callback();
                //cardInserted = function(function(){console.log("Ponowne wpisanie PINu");});
            }
        }
    }
    else if (digitStatus == 1)
    {

    }


}
```

You need to create much more variables to control your machine. Your add/delete digit function had conditions that were badly written and only worked if the text on the screen was short enough.

```
var inputLength = 0;
addDigit = function(digit){
                //numKeyValue = numKeyValue instanceof MouseEvent ? this.value : numKeyValue;{

            if (inputLength < pinLength) {
                onScreen.innerHTML += this.value;
                inputLength++;
            }
            //if (onScreen.innerHTML == 1234) console.log("PIN został wprowadzony");
        },
delDigit = function(){
            if (inputLength >= 0) {
                onScreen.innerHTML = onScreen.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
                inputLength--;
            }
        };
```

If you want to empty the screen at any moment you can insert `onScreen.innerHTML = '';` anywhere
ps: Thanks for the exercise and nice automat you made there.

Comment: thank you, it works. Although i have two questions: 1. which function points your callback()? 2. How can i make this function, if pin is wrong, to refresh screen automatically by using setTimeout(), instead of click card button every time i want to enter PIN again?
@HopefullyHelpful

Comment: 1. I just edited your code and just let it there. 2. I added the code and an explanation. You should create much more variables !!! Don't forget to accept my answer if it helped.